# Custom made advertisement with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, iad, ads

I have an agreement with a company (read: one single company) who would like to place an ad in an application I am creating. Since this is only one company, I figure that iAd is not the solution for me. This does, however, raise two questions:

1) Is it possible to open a link in safari from a webpage loaded into a UIWebView (I think via Javascript or similar techniques)?

2) Will Apple even accept an app with this kind of ads in it?

Thanks
Kasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple should have no issue with this type of ad. If you look at the UIWebView's delegate protocol, there is a way to override the behavior when you click a link, and you could then redirect the user to MobileSafari rather than processing the request in the UIWebView.

If you want the whole ad to be clickable, you could subclass UIWebView and override touch handlers on the (UI)View, or you could probably add a tap gesture recognizer.

-

This is the delegate method you'll want to implement, make it return NO and then take the URLRequest, get the URL and open the link with your UIApplication:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful stuff. I hadn't even thought about overriding delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Apple will have no problem with this. In iOS apps you can even use ad providers other than iAd.

If you have a `UIWebView`, you could possibly show the advertisement in that view, without launching Safari. Otherwise you can use

`shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request`

to intercept the click. This is a UIWebViewDelegate method that is called when a link is touched/clicked.

[Here](http://dougdiego.com/2008/10/12/open-link-in-safari/) you can find a full example.

Comment: Thanks to you also, especially the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static images to display the ad instead of HTML you can use [JPAdvertisement](https://github.com/joepasq/JPAdvertisement). Its even made in the same sizes as iAd.

Comment: I will take a look at JPAdvertisement as well. Thanks.

Comment: Also: I specifically implemented support for LinkShare URLs, if that is of any interest.

Comment: You supply images in the bundle along with a .plist file. "In order to load an ad from disk JPAdvertisement uses a plist, the name of which is passed to it via loadAdFromPlistNamed:. In that plist it looks for four keys; the adURL, affiliatedLink boolean, and file names of png images for landscape and portrait ads depending upon what device it is currently running on."

Comment: Okay. It seems like the tool for me.